# Mysql Alter table can you cast for default value?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

> ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN Created datetime DEFAULT
>   CAST('0001-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) NOT NULL;

One of our providers is generating this sql for an EF migration and the syntax is throwing an error for mysql.

Is it possible to use cast for a default value in mysql?

Comment: Are there any reason to have such strange default datetime value? I'd prefer to have NULL instead.

Comment: The default is for Identity Server 4 EF storage, I'm sure they have specific reasons for that particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cast()` is unnecessary.  The value is automatically converted to the correct type:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN Created datetime DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00' NOT NULL;
```

MySQL allows constants for default values but does not permit expressions.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know and I'll pass that along to them. Appreciate it!